# Spring LdapTemplate method to test if entry exists?

Tags: spring, ldap, spring-ldap

is there any method in Spring `LdapTemplate` that tests if an entry exists?

I could do a search, but it seems clunky if I know the specific DN that I want to check for.  (My use case: checking referential integrity from a group entry to make sure the corresponding user DNs listed under `uniqueMember` actually exist.)

Comment: I take it you are looking for some sort of `boolean exists(DN)` method? AFAIK there is no such method. You could use the `lookup(DN)` method but it either returns the object if it exists or throws a `NameNotFoundException` if no object could be found. So you would need to catch the exception. Would that work for you?

Answer (score 2):

Provided that you ldapTemplate has baseDN set up (e.g. `o=mycorp,dc=com`) and you want to check whether an rdn exists (e.g. `ou=people`):

```
private static boolean rdnExists(LdapTemplate ldapTemplate, String rdn) {
    try {
        ldapTemplate.lookup(rdn);
        return true;
    } catch (org.springframework.ldap.NamingException ne) {
        return false;
    }
}
```